# Complie riscv-gnu-toolchain on MacOS Error

Tags: riscv, gnu-toolchain

I compile gnu-tool-chain on my Mac, and get some error message
I'm in the riscv-gnu-toolchain root directory, and

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/opt/riscv-gnu-toolchain
make
```

I get

```
...
/Volumes/CaseSensitive/riscv-gnu-toolchain/riscv-gdb/readline/rltty.c:83:7: error:
      implicit declaration of function 'ioctl' is invalid in C99
      [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  if (ioctl (tty, TIOCGWINSZ, &w) == 0)
      ^
/Volumes/CaseSensitive/riscv-gnu-toolchain/riscv-gdb/readline/rltty.c:720:3: error:
      implicit declaration of function 'ioctl' is invalid in C99
      [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  ioctl (fildes, TIOCSTART, 0);
  ^
/Volumes/CaseSensitive/riscv-gnu-toolchain/riscv-gdb/readline/rltty.c:759:3: error:
      implicit declaration of function 'ioctl' is invalid in C99
      [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  ioctl (fildes, TIOCSTOP, 0);
  ^
3 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [rltty.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-readline] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [stamps/build-gdb-newlib] Error 2
```

My MacOS version is 10.15.7.
Should I add some headers file in somewhere?